# Comment traduire le « to » anglais quand il remplace un verbe ?

Tags: verbes, infinitif

En anglais, on peut remplacer un infinitif par « to » si le verbe qu'on rappelle est évident :

> Will you do the thing?
>   I'm hoping **to**.

Est-ce qu'on peut faire quelque chose de semblable en français ? Comment ?

Comment: I'd go with *J'y espère* or *J'y veux*.

Comment: @iBugauxerreurs You can't say that, without the least doubt! Neither one of the two is a possibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En français, on a facilement tendance à omettre les éléments qui sont supposés évidents. Dans sa forme la plus courte, cela donnerait :

> Tu vas le faire ?
>
> J'espère.

On peut toutefois trouver quelques variantes qui pourraient retranscrire le rôle de *to* dans la phrase originale anglaise :

> Je l'espère. (*`l'` remplace `le faire`*)
>
> J'y compte bien. (*`y` remplace `le faire`*)

Si le locuteur a choisi le **present continuous** plutôt que le présent simple pour traduire, par exemple, un engagement émotionnel, vous pourriez utiliser :

> J'espère bien.
>
> J'espère vraiment.
>
> J'y compte bien. (*Le `bien`, nécessaire dans cette locution, vient marquer l'enthousiasme du locuteur*)

Comment: Votre caractérisation de l'utilisation de la particule « to » dépasse la réalité ; il n'est question ici que de tournures propres aux langages germaniques, dans lesquels les prépositions sont rappelées ou retenues (particulièrement nécessaire en anglais dans le concept du "phrasal verb" comme il ne constitue une unité lexicale qu'en vertu de la preposition (to amount to)). Le mot « bien » est emphatique ; dans l'exemple que vous donnez on le traduit très bien par la tournure du « do » emphatique mais pas par « to » : « I do hope I will. ». « I'm hoping to. » est une simple assertion.

Comment: Vous avez raison, je ne voulais pas insinuer que **to** avait le rôle de pronom. Pour autant, c'est une trace de la proposition qui a été omise (*to do the thing*), et en ce sens, les pronoms **le** et **y** peuvent retranscrire cette omission. Concernant l'emphase, ce n'est pas **to** qui l'introduit mais le **present continuous**, qui marque, à mon sens, un engagement supérieur à l'usage du présent simple. Un anglophone pourrait peut-être me donner son opinion là-dessus ?

Comment: Je ne considère pas que  votre explication serait de donner un rôle de pronom à « to » mais que la traduction de « I'm hoping to. » ou de « I hope. » n'a pas la marque d'emphase que l'on trouve dans « J'espère bien. ». Il n'est pas question de « **le** » et de «  **y** », je suis d'accord sur ces points-là. Je reste décidé à maintenir que le présent continu ne marque pas l'emphase. (champ 1)

Comment: Que le présent continu marque un engagement supérieur est une théorie qui pourrait se tenir, je n'ai aucune assurance là-dessus, mais pas au point d'être équivalent à l'emphase exprimée par « bien » (à mon avis il vaut mieux supprimer cela de votre réponse).

Comment: J'ai édité la réponse pour modérer mon propos suite à vos remarques.

Comment: Vous ne changez pratiquement rien en fait et conservez au présent continu ce qui pour moi est une nouvelle valeur; Le TLFi nous dit que « bien » dans votre exemple est utilisé « pour appuyer une affirmation, pour s'autoriser d'un cas analogue, en réponse à une objection implicite ou explicite » et donc on utiliserait le présent continu pour appuyer une affirmation; cela n'est pas la valeur du présent continu; je n'en ai jamais entendu parler, on ne mentionne cela  dans aucune grammaire .

Comment: La grammaire indique que le présent continue indique une action qui se prolonge dans le temps. Appliqué à l'espoir, je vois mal comment interpréter cela autrement que par un investissement émotionnel persistant. Quelque chose qui reste à l'esprit du sujet et qui le préoccupe. Je reste convaincu que mes 3 dernières propositions sont de meilleures traductions dans ce contexte que les propositions précédentes.

Comment: Je viens de vérifier le traducteur DeepL et pour la traduction de « I'm hoping to. » le retour principal est « J'espère que oui. », ce qui est aussi correct que « J'espère »; cependant, ce traducteur propose des alternatives et on y trouve « J'espère le faire. », « Je l'espère bien. » et « J'espère bien. ». On peut donc conclure que si la précision fait défaut, ces correspondances sont utilisées et vous pouvez citer le traducteur (qui n'est pas toujours exact, à ne pas oublier); il n'en est pas moins que l'on en arrive à ne pas faire de différence entre « J'espère. » et « J'espère bien. ».

Answer (score 1):

There does not exist in French a true equivalent for the use of the preposition as a summing-up for a complement that has been used in the preceding phrase, complement that is apparently often an infinitival clause but not always. Instead, in French a pronoun is used : **le**, **ça**, **y**, **en**. (I have no certitude that there aren't more than four, though.)

- They are going to *tell the mayor to do something about it*. Are they really going **to**?

> Ils vont demander au maire de faire quelque chose. Vont-ils vraiment **le** faire ?

- -- We'll have to *go faster*. -- Are you allowed **to**?

> -- Nous allons devoir aller plus vite. -- Vous **y** êtes autorisé ?

- -- All the striking workers will *gather in this place tomorrow*. -- Do they have **to**?

> -- Tous les travailleurs en grève se réuniront à cet endroit demain. -- **Ça** leur est nécessaire ?

- -- The teachers have the possibility to put pressure on the administration. -- Do they intend **to**?

> -- Les enseignants ont la possibilité de faire pression sur l'administration. -- Ils **en** ont l'intention ?

The given example is translated as follows.

- Will you do the thing?
- I'm hoping to.

> Ferez-vous cela/ça ? *or* le ferez-vous? (*formal*) _ Vous ferez ça/cela ? (*colloquial*)
>   Je **l**'espère.

Instead of "Je l'espère." the speaker may however say "J'espère ça.(!)" and adopt any one tone of voice in a variety of them from  self-assured  to cocky or angry, so as to connote his/her state of mind; of course, that can be associated with only a particularised context and not the most general one.

Comment: Like Monty w/the Arnhem bridgehead, I think maybe you went "un exemple trop loin" with your last, boils-down-to, example. While "it boils down to" certainly is a way to summarize something mentioned earlier, I see the **"quoi"** in "C'est à **quoi** ..." as simply a fairly literal translation of the **"what"** in "That's **what** ..." and not as a summary of whatever the **"to"** stands for in "boils down **to**" (w/"revient **à**" covering "boils down **to**"" nicely, w/out the need or hint of summing-up). Maybe a better example w/"quoi" could be "Il y a de quoi//Il n'y a pas de quoi".

Comment: @PapaPoule It seemed a little tricky, even though I made up this example, but I'm convinced finally that, so to speak, it is all in the pronoun "what" and not in "to". Glad you caught that. May I ask you? What does the code  "w/" stand for?

Comment: I try to avoid using [this abbreviation of "with"](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/w-with.1010862/) but when my long-winded comments exceed the character limit it (& the ampersand) sometimes let's me keep everything together in one post.

Comment: Sorry, but *j'espère ça* is definitely incorrect. The same goes for *Ferez-vous ça ?*.

Comment: @Sharcoux No hard feelings, express your opinions freely. I agree the form is unusual; I'd rather say personally "C'est ce que vous ferez ?" or colloquially "Vous ferez ça ?"; however, in print the following pair of sentences is commonly found : "Je vois ça.", "Je comprends ça."; similarly, you can find "j'explique ça", "j'entends ça", "Je veux ça" and that's already 5 verbs; I can't see what's so special about "espérer"; it's true that you don't find "J'espère ça." in print, but are we under the obligation of having heard all the possible combinations, (champ 1)

Comment: @Sharcoux of having them recorded in print in order to be able to find them legitimate. Is it the case that because civilisation hasn't yet exploited or explored all possibilities -- how could the contrary be? -- and that there is therefore no trace of a particular instance of a usage, which nevertheless exists on the basis of a general model (veb_ça), we should abstain from using it, use only what is sufficiently familiar? According to that principle, come the day of the creation of a new fruit (champ 2)

Comment: @Sharcoux  through the use of one technology or other, fruit X, and as "manger un fruit X" hasn't ever yet been spoken or written we forbid ourselves using that form. I can't assert I've heard that specific form (J'espère ça.) in my whole life only one single time but it is according to a model which I am sufficiently sure of in what concerns the use of "ça", which, let's mention it by the way, is prefered as it is quite similar to a so-called tonic pronoun (intonation are possible on that pronoun whereas they are not with "le"). (fin)

Comment: I checked the occurrences of "J'espère ça" in Google, and found out that the results are globally from people making a lot of grammar mistakes in the rest of their sentences. Of course, you could always decide to speak French your own way, but generally, people agree that usage define the rules. In any case, I would not recommend teaching people here things that are not used by natives...

Comment: @Sharcoux It seems that you ignore entirely the principle I state; anyway, may I ask on what precise ground you reject that particular case of a general construction?

Comment: On the ground that in 30 years, I've never heard "j'espère ça" anywhere and when looking on the internet the sources using it are far from good references. I understand what you mean by having a "model" about "ça", but unfortunately, it seems that our language likes more exceptions than models ;)

Comment: *It seems that you ignore entirely the principle I state* -> I don't think I did, but maybe I misunderstood your comments. If so, please forgive me.

Comment: @Sharcoux As one more peculiarity worth reflecting about I'll propose this question to your consideration. Following the words  "C'est-ce qu'il vont faire." the answer "**Vous feriez ça ?**", you'll have to agree, is perfectly standard; yet there is no trace of it in print. Moreover, how can you accept this instance and reject "Vous ferez ça ?", which is nothing else than the colloquial form of "Ferez-vous ça ?"?

Comment: "Vous feriez ça" leads to 32000 results in Google and most of them use a fine level of French. Mostly press articles. I might have been harsh on "Vous ferez ça ?". There are some very special contexts and sentences where it would fit (yet, only 10000 results on Google), but I would definitely not recommend it here. **Vous allez le faire ?** (*futur proche*) seems much much more appropriate in this context.

Comment: @Sharcoux Right, the uncomplicated context calls naturally for the pronoun "le", I do agree with that; only a particular context may justify the use of "ça". I did mention that in my answer, although as a later correction.

Comment: Let's say we understood each other on this part. Remains the *J'espère ça.* in your answer that, I'm sorry, is really incorrect. The only results you'll find on google would refer to "j'espère que ça xxx" where the *que* would have been omitted. A mistake usually made by kids in spoken language. Definitely not something you would like to learn here.

Comment: @Sharcoux I can't resolve myself to tell someone that an instance with "espérer" is incorrect while all sorts of verbs are used that way; there is no logic, no principle at work that we might rely on to claim there is an error in doing so, merely the whimsies of an overwheming majority; how many are des occasions for "Je vous donne ça.", "Je vous dis ça (tout de suite)." in Everyday speech? Countless! There is no end of the cases of free constructions  fitting a given context; here isone more: "Je donne ça, et c'est tout." with stress on "ça" so as to impart the idea of "ne que ça".  (champ1)

Comment: @Sharcoux I can agree with you on the count of there being a possibility of an awkward use of "ça" when the speaker fails to match form with context, but correct language that is being misused is rife, and I'll have to concede again that in a plain context people will say 'Je l'espère.". However, when I have to hear things such as "Il espère bien ça." and find them acceptable, I can't introduce discriminatory standards based on the change of person, tense, or absence of an adverb; those remain details proper to the context.  (champ 2)

Comment: @Sharcoux "C'est ce que j'espère." and "J'espère ça." are synonymous for me. Nevertheles, feel free to add a negative vote to my answer. (fin)